# freebase fields appear on web, but empty when using API

Tags: freebase, mql

I am trying to get the notable_for field for this person, which appears on the web site

http://www.freebase.com/m/01z7_f

but this query returns an empty field

```
[{
  "type": "/common/topic",
  "notable_for": [],
  "mid": "/m/01z7_f",
  "name": null
}]
```

Am I using the right query here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notable_for` is a "synthetic property" which can't be queried via MQL.  It is included in the Topic API though, so that's the thing to use if you need this property.

EDIT: One additional note -- the `notable_for` and `notable_type` properties are included in recent Freebase data dumps, so they can also be accessed that way:

```
$ zgrep ns:m.01z7_f freebase-rdf-2013-06-30-00-00.gz | grep notable
ns:m.01z7_f     ns:common.topic.notable_for     ns:g.1258t0lp5.
ns:m.01z7_f     ns:common.topic.notable_types   ns:m.01xrzmg.
```